# Find links/relationships between 2 variables/objects in the code

Tags: visual-studio, ide, doxygen, code-analysis, call-graph

EDIT:

---

I found that doxygen can generate call graphs for classes, but I could not find any options or examples where the call(er) graph is generated for public/private members of the class(es) such as fields, methods, etc.? See the example that I provided below.

---

Is it possible to find links/relationships between 2 variables/objects in the code using some IDE tools and code editors, i.e. in Visual Studio, Sublime, etc.

e.g.

```
a=func(b,c);
w=func(a,c);
```

Here `w` and `b` are indirectly related to each other.

In convoluted code it is very difficult to manually find such relationships.

I understand that reflection and dynamic nature of some languages can limit such analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the language you are looking to use. If I take a guess and say C/C++ you can use [CCTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2368) and [Cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) in general for this functionality. Most open source developers use Cscope extensively for this purpose.

Eclipse CDT also has [call graph's](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.linuxtools.callgraph.docs%2FLinux_Tools_Project%2FCallgraph%2FUser_Guide%2FGeneral-Usage.html). It is a bit of a pain to work outside of VisualStudio for this purpose I know. But cost is part of the reason to use open source instead.

Your best bet to cover all languages for the purpose of browsing is [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html). This works with a fair amount of editors and all the languages you listed. With that large a list of languages and use cases its probably worth your time to learn either vim or emacs and the integrations supported here.

For Python you can also take a look at [pyscope](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycscope/) with [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/). Another excellent alternative for Python is [Rope](http://rope.sourceforge.net/). Rope supports finding definitions and usages as part of its standard set of tools.

Most developers do not need CCTree as browsing code bases with cscope is relatively straightforward. I have used exuberant ctags + emacs on a huge variety of language for years. It takes a touch of time to learn, but the upsides are
it's free, portable, and powerful. Another alternative to CCTree is [codegraph](http://codegraph.rubyforge.org/) for some of your target languages.

Comment: I'm interested in C#/VB.NET, python and fortran

Comment: I awarded you +100 in hope that you can improve this answer.

Comment: I have added some more info for you based on the languages you listed. In general if you are willing to venture into the vim/emacs world this should meet your needs as a developer.

Answer (score 1):

Found a list of tools and comparison:

https://github.com/OpenGrok/OpenGrok/wiki/Comparison-with-Similar-Tools

EDIT

---

possible in doxygen, but only for classes and their relationships

[image: from web]

---

I found it, this is code map in VS Ultimate:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-visual-studio-2015-preview-availability.aspx

[image: Developer can filter link types on Code Map]

Comment: roslyn can generate "Directed Syntax Graph" https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Syntax%20Visualizer#Syntax